# WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, babeljs, config

been trying to build my nuxt application but i keep getting this (WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB) i have tried setting  performance: {
maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
maxAssetSize: 512000
},but still gets the same error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BWs3.jpg
[here is my nuxt.config.js]

Comment: Please post your config file and the complete error message as text, no images.